# What's a chained double bang operator (`!!`) in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, operators

I've recently ran into this TSX syntax:

```
<SomeElement
  onClick={() => {
    setSearchInput('')
    ref.current!!.focus()
  }}
/>
```

`SomeElement` has a type of `React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<SomeInterface & React.RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>>`

`ref.current` has a type of
`React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>.current: HTMLInputElement | null`

Could anyone explain what's up with the double bang (`!!`) before `.focus()`? According to linter, it is valid syntax.

Where is this documented? I've searched MDN for the list of operators and I haven't found anything relevant.
I know what a double negation is (e.g: replacement for `Boolean()`), but this doesn't seem to be the case. Or... is it?

Comment: It's a typo of `ref.current!.focus()`

Comment: @Certain, so you're saying it's a valid typo? And that only once would suffice?

Comment: It's a syntactically valid typo that there probably should be a linter rule for somewhere in an ideal world, but it's such an odd occurrence that I'm not surprised if there isn't

Comment: `null!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!` is valid typescript. So is `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!false`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. It is, indeed, TS, I just though it's unrelated to typescript.